# How do I delete "filename.txt" in "blah\bleurgh\filename.txt" in VBS?

Tags: string, vbscript

such a silly question I know, but I want to remove the filename in a string such as

```
"blah\bleurgh\filename.txt"
```

To delete the extension I would do

```
strFile = Left(strFile, InStrRev(strFile, ".") - 1)
```

But doing similiar to delete the filename at the end does nothing, e.g.

```
tempStrFile = Left(tempStrFile, InStrRev(tempStrFile, "\") - 1)
```

A "\\" doesn't work either, incase it was an escape character issue.

Many thanks!

edit: for further information what I want to do is if given a filename such as "filename.txt" I want to output "output_filename.csv" - I have no problems with this.

If I get a directory though such as "blah\filename.txt" I have difficulty sticking output in the middle to get "blah\output_filename.csv"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want, then your code works for me, the following code:

```
dim tempStrFile
tempStrFile = "blah\bleurgh\filename.txt"
tempStrFile = Left(tempStrFile, InStrRev(tempStrFile, "\") - 1)
tempStrFile = tempStrFile & "\output_filename.csv"
msgbox tempStrFile
```

will output `blah\bleurgh\output_filename.csv` which I belive is what you want.